# How to parallel compute to improve efficiency in pyspark instead of loop about "for" ？

Tags: for-loop, pyspark, processing-efficiency

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(6 ,5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print df
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
for col in ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']:
    df_groupby = spark_df.groupby(col).count(F.col('a'))
    spark_df = spark_df.join(df_groupby, col, how = 'left')
```

output:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
5  25  26  27  28  29
```

I have a big data to deal like this type

I think loop about "for" will reduce efficiency

Who can tell me how to parallel compute to improve efficiency in pyspark

Sincere thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the desired output? The code you provided has a number of errors.

Comment: I want multiple groupby to compute parallelly

Comment: check if this works: `spark_df.select('*', *[ F.count('a').over(Window.partitionBy(c)).alias('{}_cnt'.format(c)) for c in spark_df.columns[1:] ])`